Unable to Simulate Ctrl+Alt+Home to Activate Remote Desktop Connection Bar in PowerShell and C#
I'm attempting to automate the activation of the Azure Remote Desktop Connection bar by simulating the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Home using PowerShell and C# code. To accomplish this, I use the keybd_event function from the user32.dll library to simulate key presses.
The script I’ve created works well for other combinations like Ctrl + A, Ctrl + V, and even Ctrl + Alt + Tab. However, when trying to simulate Ctrl + Alt + Home (a Remote Desktop-specific shortcut for activating the connection bar), it doesn't work. I’ve confirmed that this isn’t an issue with the script or the individual key calls, as all other shortcut simulations function as expected. Here’s the relevant code snippet:
# Simulate Ctrl + Alt + Home
[KeyboardSend]::KeyDown([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Control)
[KeyboardSend]::KeyDown([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::LMenu)   # Alt key
[KeyboardSend]::KeyDown([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Home)    # Home key down
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100                                 # Hold keys briefly
[KeyboardSend]::KeyUp([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Home)      # Home key up
[KeyboardSend]::KeyUp([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::LMenu)     # Alt key up
[KeyboardSend]::KeyUp([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Control)   # Ctrl key up

I’m not creating a new shortcut but rather using PowerShell to automate this particular keyboard sequence. Since the script works for other combinations, I suspect there may be restrictions when trying to simulate Remote Desktop-specific shortcuts.
My question is: Are there known restrictions when simulating Remote Desktop shortcuts (like Ctrl + Alt + Home) in PowerShell or other languages?

Are you running this script on the client or the server? If you are doing this from the server-side (the machine which accepts the connection rather than the machine the user is sitting at) then I suspect the issue is that Ctrl+Alt+Home simply isn't a shortcut that's handled by the server, it's probably caught by the client before it even gets to the server.

@Charlieface I'm  running the script within the remote session itself

Yeah that's not going to work. The server doesn't know anything about the client's system and can't control it.

Is there any way to work around it?

Not from the server-side that I'm aware. I've had a quick look at the protocol spec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/5073f4ed-1e93-45e1-b039-6e30c385867c and I can't see any messages that would be relevant for that. Is there any reason you can't do this from the client side?

Thank you so much for looking into it. I understand what you mean. I'm actually working within a remote environment where I use Citrix to connect to Azure desktop and inside I use Remote Desktop connection.
